# error 404 al intentar insertar mediante ajax

Tags: php, mysql, jquery, ajax, mvc

estoy intentando implementar inserciones mediante ajax en mi página web. Tengo un .js con el siguiente método:

```
    function meterCancion(idUsuario, idCancion) {
     $.ajax({
      url: "insertarCancion.php",
      data: {idusuario:idUsuario, idcancion:idCancion},
      type: "POST",
      success: function(data) {
       alert(data);
      },
      error: function(xhr, status, error) {
     alert(xhr.responseText);
    }
     });
    };
```

y en la misma carpeta que ese js tengo el archivo php de la url que viene a ser:

```
    <?php

    $idUsuario = $_POST['idusuario'];
    $idCancion = $_POST['idcancion'];
    $sql = "INSERT INTO usuario_cancion VALUES (:idUsuario, 
    :idCancion);";
    include_once __DIR__ . 'conexionBd.php';
    try {
      $con = (new ConexionBd)->getConexion();
      $snt = $con->prepare($sql);
      $snt->bindParam(':idUsuario', $idUsuario);
      $snt->bindParam(':idCancion', $idCancion);
      $snt->execute();
      $snt->nextRowset();
    } catch (PDOException $ex) {
      throw $ex;
    } finally{
     $snt = null;
     $con = null;
    }
    ?>
```

al clicar en la web para que me ejecute el js me sale este mensaje de error:
[image: error 404]

Comment: Prueba a poner la página php del ajax al mismo nivel que la página php que llama al js

Comment: @JoseJavierSegura vale, asi si me funciona, tengo un sistema MVC y si lo pongo a la par que index.php me va, pero no me parece correcto tenerlo fuera, como haría para poder llamarlo estando dentro de x carpeta?

Comment: En la url, deberias poner la carpeta/insertarcancion.php. Ten en cuenta que la llamada es a nivel del index.php y no del fichero js

Comment: @JoseJavierSegura vale ya está, muchísimas gracias, como marco el post como resuelto entonces?

Comment: Puedes poner tú misma la solución que has encontrado y marcas la respuesta como correcta